# How much currency do you get for a duplicate cosmetic?

Tags: overwatch

When you open a loot crate and receive a cosmetic you already own, it is automatically turned into coins. How much do you get, exactly? Is it a constant amount, a fraction of its unlock cost, or something else?

Comment: No idea. I got 50 coins the one time I got coins in a Loot Box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Overwatch is still in the early productions, but a popular (and seemingly true) theory is that every duplicate gives roughly a fifth of it's price. For example, a 5C for a 25C spray or icon, 50C for any 250C epic, 200C for a 1000C Legendary skin, and so on. This is true for all things obtained with a preset price set on them.

This is supported, as in another Blizzard™ game [Hearthstone](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjA14mU1MjMAhVT22MKHc8-Bk8QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fus.battle.net%2Fhearthstone%2Fen%2F&usg=AFQjCNGm9X0Fk2tz14pnst0iNpp2RgVQBw&bvm=bv.121421273,d.cGc) there's a similar system. The cost of a legendary card is 1600, but if you get duplicate, you can disenchant it only for 400. The difference is that in Hearthstone, it's a one fourth, while in Overwatch, it appears to be one fifth.

There's an [ongoing conversation about the topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4c5jwo/some_statistics_on_cosmetics/?) over on Reddit that offers some more insight, but to answer your question, much proof as there is behind the theory, there's no "for-sure" answer that can be provided at the moment.

Comment: Hm. Not sure if that's the full story. I got 50c coins (to go from the starting 50 to 100) despite not having any 250 Epics.

Comment: @RavenDreamer You get credit for duplicate cosmetics (where it shows the cosmetic and also a "duplicate +credit" note) but you can also win straight-up credits from the loot box.

Comment: @Troyen Specifically, you can win 15, 50, 150, or 500 credits depending on the loot quality (common, rare, epic, and legendary respectively).  And yes, seeing you got a legendary and then seeing it was just 500 coins is depressing.

Comment: @Troyen Makes sense. That'll be what happened, then.