# Can you get duplicate items out of Loot Box?

Tags: overwatch

I've never gotten a duplicate item out of a Loot Box, but I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Does it automatically turn into gold depending on the rarity of the item?

How does the game handle duplicate items?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can indeed get a duplicate item from a loot box. On getting a duplicate it is converted into gold, but not at the full cost of the item.

[Here is a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/45grcw/why_are_duplicate_items_worth_so_little/) with more discussion on the topic. They claim some items will net you 10%-20% of the items original cost. You may also  be interested in [How much currency do you get for a duplicate cosmetic?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264905/how-much-currency-do-you-get-for-a-duplicate-cosmetic)

I don't think you'll get any extra gold here though!

Comment: These questions aren't duplicates, since they asking different things, but they are related. Also, there's nothing wrong with linking to other sites, and we actually encourage including sources to back up your answer if you have them.

Comment: @Wipqozn well technically the question itself (How much currency do you get for a duplicate cosmetic?) answers this question... because in order for that to be a valid question, you have to receive currency for duplicates in the first place.